# AWS backup is not in the list of command line interface commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I'm trying to use `aws backup` on my AWS server through command-line interface, but it's not in the list of available commands. How do I add this in?

Currently when I run

```
aws backup
```

I get the following:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

acm                                      | apigateway                              
application-autoscaling                  | autoscaling                             
budgets                                  | cloudformation                          
cloudfront                               | cloudhsm                                
cloudsearch                              | cloudsearchdomain                       
cloudtrail                               | cloudwatch
```

etc.

there's no `backup` in there.

How do I launch `aws backup` commands then?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your *aws-cli*. More likely than not you’ve got an old version that doesn’t yet have *backup* support.

What’s your `aws --version` output?

Answer (score 0):

```
>> aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.59 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 exe/AMD64

>> aws backup help

backup
^^^^^^
Description
***********
AWS Backup is a unified backup service designed to protect AWS services (etc)
```